# Testing multidomain Rails 3 app with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, capybara

I want to test my multidomain RoR3 App.

Here's my test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'blueprints'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase

end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara

  def host
    "http://#{subdomain}.lvh.me:3000"
  end

  def subdomain
    @subdomain ? @subdomain : 'demostore'
  end

  def visit(url)
    super("http://#{subdomain}.lvh.me:3000#{url}")
  end
end
```

And my integration test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @subdomain = 'demostore'
    # creating stuff
  end

  def teardown
    # deleting stuff
  end

  test "user views product list" do
    visit('/')
    assert page.has_css?('ul.product-listing')
    assert page.has_xpath?("//ul[@class='product-listing']/li", :count => 12)
  end

  test "user views product page" do
    product = Product.first

    visit('/')
    find(:xpath, "//ul[@class='product-listing']/li/a[1]").click
    save_and_open_page
  end

end
```

And I'm sure the link exists. There is problem with clicking and filling stuff.

```
click_link('Existent link title')
```

doesn't work too.

I think the default Capybara's driver Rack::Test could have problems with this multidomain stuff?

Comment: Would you be able to share your solution? What did you set the port to?
Thanks!
Ciaran

Comment: Yes, I would like to see the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your setup, call this rack::test function, which will change your host's value. Well, it changes the host that gets returned about the fake web request.

```
host! "#{store.subdomain}.example.com"
```

Comment: This won't work. I've solved it already by setting host and port in Capybara's settings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i'm using multidomain stuff so I had to use lvh.me which resolves localhost. You can do the same think by setting in Your /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 subdomain.yourapp.local
```

and then use this domain.

I've overwritten Capybara's visit method with sth like that:

```
def visit(link)
  super("mysubdomain.lvh.me:3000#{link}")
end
```

but problem persisted because when Capybara clicked for example link, the visit method was not used and my host was not requested. Which was? I don't know - probably the default one.

So solution is to set host and port in Capybara settings:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara

  Capybara.default_host = "subdomain.yourapp.local"
  Capybara.server_port = 3000
  # ... rest of stuff here
end
```

Comment: The problem I had with setting `Cabybara.default_host` is that it sets it globally for all specs. This was causing some of my previous specs to break. "The author of Capybara, Jonas Nicklas, [states](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ruby-capybara/HMKCIDJAA6w/Ky3TA_-o3-0J) 'Never change Capybara.default_host, just don't.' and recommends that subdomains are visited explicitly." (from http://minimul.com/capybara-and-subdomains.html)

Comment: got to go with Christian's solution in comment above. That is the real answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a problem with rack-test.

But there is a fork of it by [hassox](https://github.com/hassox/rack-test.git) that just solved it for me.
It's just a couple of commits that really matter, in case you want to check what the changes are.

This is how my Gemfile looks:

```
group :test, :cucumber do
  gem 'rack-test', :git => "https://github.com/hassox/rack-test.git"
  gem 'capybara', '= 0.4.1.2'
  gem 'capybara-envjs', '= 0.4.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '>= 0.3.2'
  gem 'pickle', '>= 0.3.4'
end
```

And then I just make sure to

```
visit('http://my_subdomain.example.com')
```

in my steps. Now I'm trying to understand what would make url helpers work with subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick setup that may help you out...

rails 3.2+ testing custom subdomains using cucumber capybara with pow setup:

https://gist.github.com/4465773

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share what I found to be a great solution for this problem. It involves creating a helper method to prepend URLs with the desired subdomain, doesn't overwrite any Capybara methods, and works with the Rack::Test and capybara-webkit drivers. In fact, it will even work in specs which do not even use Capybara. (source: http://minimul.com/capybara-and-subdomains.html)

### The Spec Helper Method

```
# spec/support/misc.helpers.rb
def hosted_domain(options = {})
  path = options[:path] || "/" # use root path by default
  subdomain = options[:subdomain] || 'www'
  if example.metadata[:js]
    port = Capybara.current_session.driver.server_port
    url = "http://#{ subdomain }.lvh.me:#{ port }#{ path }"
  else
    url = "http://#{ subdomain }.example.com#{ path }"
  end
end
```

---

### And to illustrate it's use, here are two examples:

#### Used in a Feature Spec (with Capybara)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Accounts" do
  # Creates an account using a factory which sequences
  # account subdomain names
  # Additionally creates users associated with the account
  # using FactoryGirl's after callbacks (see FactoryGir docs)
  let (:account) { FactoryGirl.create(:account_with_users) })

  it "allows users to sign in" do
    visit hosted_domain(path: new_sessions_path, subdomain: account.subdomain)

    user = account.users.first

    fill_in "email", with: user.email
    fill_in "password", with: user.password
    click_button "commit"

    # ... the rest of your specs
  end
end
```

#### Used in a Request Spec (without Capybara)

```
#spec/requests/account_management_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

describe "Account management" do
  # creates an account using a factory which sequences
  # account subdomain names
  let (:account) { FactoryGirl.create(:account) })

  it "shows the login page" do
    get hosted_domain(path: "/login", subdomain: account.subdomain)
    expect(response).to render_template("sessions/new")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean solution is to override the urls you provide to Capybara's visit method. It works well with *.lvh.me domains, which will redirect you to localhost:

```
describe "Something" do

  def with_subdomain(link)
    "http://subdomain.lvh.me:3000#{link}"
  end

  it "should do something" do
    visit with_subdomain(some_path)
  end

end
```

Or you could do the same by redefining app_host before a spec:

```
Capybara.app_host = 'http://sudbomain.lvh.me:3000'
..
visit(some_path)
```